# Adding categorical variable to a dataframe in r randomly depending on the percent times each category will appear

Tags: r, categorical-data

I am trying to simulate some data shown below for analysis in r and I need to add a column having categories'Debit & Credit' such that in the final dataset I will have '76%' debit & '24%' Credit.

```
cust_id trxn_date   trxn_id trxn_amt
1001    25-Jun-14   303703  373
1001    13-Jun-14   283268  143
1001    14-May-14   233493  580
1001    3-Apr-14    164596  155
1001    24-Mar-14   147658  651
1001    22-Mar-14   144280  229
1001    14-Mar-14   130655  100
1001    11-Mar-14   125599  170
1001    9-Mar-14    122245  674
1001    1-Mar-14    108788  223
1001    21-Feb-14   95177   68
1001    16-Feb-14   86754   689
1001    26-Jan-14   51920   141


cust_id trxn_date   trxn_id trxn_amt Trxn_type
1001    25-Jun-14   303703  373      Debit
1001    13-Jun-14   283268  143      Debit
1001    14-May-14   233493  580      Debit
1001    3-Apr-14    164596  155      Debit
1001    24-Mar-14   147658  651      Debit
1001    22-Mar-14   144280  229      Debit
1001    14-Mar-14   130655  100      Debit
1001    11-Mar-14   125599  170      Debit
1001    9-Mar-14    122245  674      Debit
1001    1-Mar-14    108788  223      Debit
1001    21-Feb-14   95177   68       Credit
1001    16-Feb-14   86754   689      Credit
1001    26-Jan-14   51920   141      Credit
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: if you consider any of the answers solved your problem, please consider accepting it as answer by checking the tick mark under the answer's voting. That way you encouurage those that devote time here for a little reputation ;)

Comment: I thought i can accept 2 answers just to show my gratitude for your time.
Looks like @mtoto and I were writing the same answer at about the same time :| – PavoDive yesterday

Comment: you can upvote as many as you like, but can accept only one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use `sample()` to randomly assign each observation to either `Debit` or `Credit` with a given probability.

```
df$Trxn_type <- sample(c("Debit", "Credit"),
                       size = nrow(df), 
                       prob = c(0.76, 0.24), replace = TRUE)
> df
#   cust_id trxn_date trxn_id trxn_amt Trxn_type
#1     1001 25-Jun-14  303703      373     Debit
#2     1001 13-Jun-14  283268      143    Credit
#3     1001 14-May-14  233493      580     Debit
#4     1001  3-Apr-14  164596      155     Debit
#5     1001 24-Mar-14  147658      651     Debit
#6     1001 22-Mar-14  144280      229    Credit
#7     1001 14-Mar-14  130655      100    Credit
#8     1001 11-Mar-14  125599      170     Debit
#9     1001  9-Mar-14  122245      674     Debit
#10    1001  1-Mar-14  108788      223     Debit
#11    1001 21-Feb-14   95177       68     Debit
#12    1001 16-Feb-14   86754      689     Debit
#13    1001 26-Jan-14   51920      141     Debit
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming your data frame is called `a`, then this will work:

```
a$type <- as.factor(sample(c("debit", "credit"), 
                           size = nrow(a), 
                           replace = TRUE, 
                           prob = c(.76, .24)))
```

what you are doing there is creating a random sample of same size as a with occurrence probabilities defined as you stated 76% and 24%.

Comment: Looks like @mtoto and I were writing the same answer at about the same time :|